# Looking for options to Overcome lightning-map Property Limitations using LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-map

I have a working solution of marking Salesforce Account Address/co-ordinates on google map using lightning-map component. However, I am looking for options to include non-standard (properties not available as part of lightning-map) fields like website and phone number to be displayed along with the standard properties. Is there any work around for that? I am attaching a screenshot of the current prototype.[image: Current Prototype]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lightning-map base component doesn't support this out of the box but you could build a custom component that replaces the location list that's displayed as a sidebar.

Here are some tips (not a complete walkthrough) on how to this:

Start by disabling the default location list view by adding `list-view="hidden"` to lightning-map.

[lightning-map](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-map/documentation) takes in an array of `mapMarkers` objects and these object have a `value` property.
Use this property to store record Ids and display the relevant information in a custom list on the side of the map (where the location list used to be).

Use the `onmarkerselect` event handler and the `selected-marker-value` attribute to keep track of marker selection:

```
onmarkerselect={handleMarkerSelect}
selected-marker-value={selectedMarkerValue}>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to have a thought about it, my thought was to make use of value property to fetch the ID and use it to fetch the additional field values and display the details using a datatable. The approach of disabling the list-view and using a custom list on the same place sounds better. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks @ForceJourney, can you mark this as the best answer then?